# Protected routes check user api

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to check my protected router. Now i want to call my api per checking user. I Try it but it doesn't work. This is my code. My react version is 17 and react-router-dom 6. I use typescript too.

my App.tsx

```
  <Routes>
        <Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

Next this is my ProtectedRoutes wrapper

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthWrapper = () => {

    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        /* =============== HERE CALL MY API CHECK =============== */
        return  <Outlet /> 
    }
     else 
    {
      return  <Navigate to="/login" replace />
    }

  };

export default AuthWrapper;
```

Now...the problem is...when i get jwt from the session storage I would like to call my per checking jwt wait and then return  or navigate to login
could someone help me? Thank's a lot

Comment: Where is `AuthWrapper` used in your app code? Is it imported as `ProtectedRoutes`? What is the `"HERE CALL MY API CHECK"` logic? As a hint it seems you should probably be using an `useEffect` hook to get your JWT token and run any asynchronous logic, and conditionally render a loading spinner or similar while the auth check is processing.

Comment: Ops! There is an error in the above code.Route AuthWrapper not ProtectedRoutes. I would implement the async call api, you would have some examples that use uffect in the wrapper???? You Know my problem but i not found any example Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The should use an `useEffect` hook to access the JWT token and run the asynchronous auth check. Use an indeterminant auth state to conditionally return early null or a loading indicator, and only after the auth check has completed allow the routed component or redirect to be rendered.

Example:

```
const AuthWrapper = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const authCheck = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const JWT = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("jwt"));

      if (!JWT) {
        setAuth(false); // or unauthorized value
        return;
      }

      try {
        /* =============== HERE CALL MY API CHECK =============== */

        // await the asynchronous logic
        const auth = await .....

        setAuth(auth);
      } catch (error) {
        // handle any Promise rejections, errors, etc...
        setAuth(false); // or unauthorized value
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    authCheck();

    return () => {
      // cancel/clean up any pending/in-flight asynchronous auth checks
    };
  }, [location.pathname]); // <-- check authentication when route changes

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return auth // or auth property if object, i.e. auth.isAuthenticated, etc...
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

[image: Edit protected-routes-check-user-api]